# SQL - Merging Tables without matching column

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have 2 tables.

**Table A**

```
ID Name Surname Hobby
```

**Table B**

```
ID Name Surname Hobby
```

Both tables have the same headlines and columns.
Now I want to merge the Tables. I do not want to delete the duplicates.
The IDs in both tables are identical. But I dont want to connect the Tables via the ID.

I want to have a new Table C with all values from A and B. So I want to append Table B under Table A.

It would be great, if some could help me. I am using MS Access 2010.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT
    ID, Name, Surname, Hobby
FROM TableA
UNION ALL
SELECT
    ID, Name, Surname, Hobby
FROM TableB
```